# angular 4 spring boot data null after subscribe method in angular 4

Tags: angular, spring-boot

im using angular 4 and  spring boot.
when i subscribe in my component the data go null alwyas . this is the example :
the first print is correct but once i print(console.log)  data == null

the service method :

```
saveEtage() {
    this.etage.nom = this.etageNomadd;
    console.log("etageNomadd = "+ this.etageNomadd);
    this.idmaisonadd = parseInt(this.modifiedtext);
    console.log(" id maison = "+ this.etage.maison+" Nom Etage = "+ this.etage.nom);

    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/saveEtage",this.etage)
      .map(resp=>resp.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

in the restControlleur i have  this methode

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveEtage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Etage saveEtage(@RequestBody Etage p) {
    System.out.println("  etage " + p.getIdEtage());
    System.out.println("  etage  name " + p.getNomEtage());
    etageRepository.save(p);
    return p;
}
```

someone can help me to resolve  this ?

Comment: is the console.log inside subscribe shows null?

Comment: You should check your backend, maybe you are sending a null object... You should also open your browser console and check the response you are receiving from your backend.

Comment: when i print  data in my service angular  data is null  in the back end object null also

Comment: Have you tried calling this method via Postman or curl? 
It would be easier to understand whether the problem is on Spring Boot or Angular side

Comment: try `return etageRepository.save(p);`

Comment: don't work form me  i think the problém was in th frontend side cause when i print data is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello i resolve the issue

1-  i create  object maison with the  same properties

```
export class Maison{
  idMaison : number;
  nomMaison : string;

  constructor( ) {
    this.idMaison= null;
    this.nomMaison = null;
  }
}
```

2- i change the relation in my frontend model from number to Maison

```
import {Maison} from "./model.maison";
    export class Etage{
      idEtage : number;
      maison : Maison;
      nomEtage : string;

      constructor() {
        this.idEtage = null;
        this.maison = null;
        this.nomEtage = null;
      }
    }
```

3- this is my save methode in the components

```
saveEtage() {
    this.etage.nomEtage = this.etageNomadd;
    let mai = new Maison();
    mai.idMaison = this.maisonSelected;
    this.etage.maison = mai;
    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/saveEtage", this.etage)
      .map(resp=>resp.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

4- my html select

```
<div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="maisonSelected" class="form-control " (ngModelChange)="onMaisonSelected($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let k of pageReservations1?.content" [value]="k.idMaison">{{k.nomMaison}}</option>
    </select>

  </div>
```

I hope this will help you thanx